# A better alternative to my approach (Symfony 1.4 modules)

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

In my quest for perfection and minimalism, I post this question here to you guys, seeking if there is a better and more alternative option than the one I have.

I have a module with two different templates. Essentially the first is a quiz template, the second is a page that displays the results of the quiz. The quiz is a form whereas the results page is not. On my quiz page, the action for the form is essentially 'module/quizResults?id='.$quizId

Now for the quiz action, I do a db query to retrieve the set of questions that belong to the quiz and then when the post takes place the action that is being called is that of quizResults, out here I must compare the answer options of my user against the correct answer options for the questions of a quiz. Essentially, I have to again query the db to retrieve the set of questions for the quizzes in another db. I feel this is a slight overkill and I am irked.

I think there can be better solutions. I can post back to the same quiz page, but then that demands more complexity on the template as well as the action making things a little murkier.

Any alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: To summarize, you have two actions which make the same query for the same data, and you want to see if you can reduce it to one query?

Comment: Haha hello user1020069 (pick a user name so we can recognize you!).

Comment: lol..ok..same guy who you been answering symfony related questions all week long

Comment: Symfony has a fairly high ramp-up before you truly hit your stride in rapid app development (RAD). I'm curious though, how come you aren't using SF2? If I weren't so vested in 1.4 I would spend the time to learn v2.

Comment: @MikePurcell I've been using s1 since just before 1.1 rolled out; I also still do new projects in 1.4 to now. (At this point, today, I would use 2.) I tried learning s2 last year, but was put off by the options in the admin generator space. AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle looks like what I would use now; Sonata rubbed me the wrong way with the Admin class; seemed like overkill when I just want to quickly get started with a scaffold.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Finally got 1.4 under control, don't have the time nor the money to invest in ramping up to 2.0. Maybe when 3.0 comes out.

Comment: no 3.0 Mike, Symfony 2.0 is the final chapter of Symfony :)

Comment: and completely disagree that Symfony has a ramp up, its worked the best for me, compare that to do actual development in Drupal and it's a pain in the backside....

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options you could implement to do what your asking, but you need to ask yourself will the added complexity outweigh the minor performance gains, especially if the queries are optimized.

Option #1: Session

When you load the questions from the quiz action, you could add the questions to the user's session, then when the user posts the quiz for the results, simply refer to the questions stored in session.

Option #2: Memcached

Same as above, but instead of storing the questions to the user session, you could store the questions into memcache, so when you calculate the results, instead of making another database query, you pull the questions from the cache layer instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to solve this the wrong way.

Performance is absolute no issue here. But what is an issue is programmer performance. If you have to manually craft each query and pass all the right variables along it's going to take a lot of your time. What you need is a framework that will allow you to build the necessary logic in a quicker way. If you know how to do this perfectly you will make a lot of money, until then you'll have to scratch along just like the rest of us :P

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the submission page should display all-good if all correct, or the incorrect ones if not, I would write a `myprojectQuestionValidator` and use that in my question form, one for each question/answer. The validator can then check each answer against the correct one in the database. Agreed with Frits, don't worry about performance - that's premature optimization IMO. Break the app into conceptual components, and worry about optimization when you need to.